# How to fix 'type error: 'float' object is not iterable' in my program?

Tags: python, function, loops, math, max

```
def formula(listA, count_zero=0, start_waiting_time = 0, result=[], service_time=random.expovariate(1.2), interarrival=1):
    for i in listA:
        if i == 1:
            result.append(max(start_waiting_time + service_time - (count_zero + 1) * interarrival), 0)
            count_zero = 0
         elif i == 0:
            count_zero += 1
    return result

# Test case
print(formula([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]))

#This returns result: TypeError 'float' object is not iterable
```

Once I remove the `max` from the equation `result.append(max(start_waiting_time + service_time - (count_zero + 1) * interarrival), 0)` then I get results but these results are not what I hoped for.

This is the code when the `max` is removed from the equation:

```
def formula(listA, count_zero=0, start_waiting_time = 0, result=[], service_time=random.expovariate(1.2), interarrival=1):
    for i in listA:
        if i == 1:
            result.append(start_waiting_time + service_time - (count_zero + 1) * interarrival)
            count_zero = 0
        elif i == 0:
            count_zero += 1
    return result

#[1.536003224186501, 1.536003224186501, 1.536003224186501, 0.5360032241865009, -0.4639967758134991]
```

These results are correct except that the result is never supposed to be negative which was the reason for me adding `max` to the equation, I was trying to tell the program to compute 0 if the result becomes negative. Therefore, the result I expected was:

```
#[1.536003224186501, 1.536003224186501, 1.536003224186501, 0.5360032241865009, 0]
```

The difference is that the last output in the result is 0 and not -0.4639967758134991.

Comment: You need to fix your parentheses. Your code is `list.append(max(...), 0)` instead of `list.append(max(..., 0))`.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python3 documentation:

> Help on built-in function max in module builtins:
>
> max(...)
>       max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
>       max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value
>
> ```
> With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
> With two or more arguments, return the largest argument. (END)
> ```

In your code, you've used max on single float value, which is result of an expression:

```
start_waiting_time + service_time - (count_zero + 1) * interarrival
```

So if you'll pass tuple with your expression and 0 to the max function, as this:

```
result.append(max((start_waiting_time + service_time - (count_zero + 1) * interarrival,0)))
```

it should work as you've expected.